# Beginner probability question: Can you help me understand the book's solution for a Poisson RV?

Tags: probability

From Sheldon Ross (enjoyable book!)

**Problem**

Suppose that earthquakes occur with λ = 2 and with 1 week as the unit of time. Find the probability distribution of the time, starting from now, until the next earthquake.

**Book Solution**

Let X denote the amount of time (in weeks) until the next earthquake. Because X will be greater than t if and only if no events occur within the next t units of time, we have,

P{X > t} = P{X = 0} = $e^{−\lambda t}$

so the probability distribution function F of the random variable X is given by

P{X $\le$ t} = 1 − P{X > t} = 1 − $e^{-\lambda t}$ = 1 − $e^{-2t}$

**My question**

It seems to me that the solution should be the P{X = t} and not P{X $\le$ t}. For example, what is the probability that it will take t weeks until the next earthquake? Then the earthquake should happen exactly at time t, versus P{X <= t}.

It seems like the book solution would tell you the probability of it happening at any time within t, including right away. This is still useful information but doesn't seem as good as knowing the probability of it happening exactly at time t.

So the solution should be P{X = t} = P{X $\le$ t} - P{X < t}

I know I'm thinking incorrectly on something, can you point out what? Thanks!

Comment: I find this phrasing confusing as if it was paraphrased from what Ross actually wrote. As written, I interpret $X$ as a continuous random variable on $[0,\infty)$ and not a discrete one, so $P(X=0) = 0$.

Comment: I am sure it should be $\mathsf P\{X{>}t\}=\mathsf P\{N_t{=}0\} = e^{-\lambda t}$, where $N_t$ is the count for events during the interval $[0;t]$.

Comment: Sorry Echan looks like I messed up the paraphrasing. There were many parts to the original question but this was the specific part I was confused on. Graham Kemp has it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to me that the solution should be the P{X = t} and not P{X $\le$ t}. For example, what is the probability that it will take t weeks until the next earthquake? Then the earthquake should happen exactly at time t, versus P{X <= t}.
>
> It seems like the book solution would tell you the probability of it happening at any time within t, including right away. This is still useful information but doesn't seem as good as knowing the probability of it happening exactly at time t.

$X$ is a continuous random variable, not a discrete one.   The probability of it having any *exact* value is zero.   Thus the *probability mass function* is $\mathsf P(X{=}t)~=~0$ and this is not useful information at all.

However, knowing the *cumulative distribution function* (CDF) is, $F_X(t)=\mathsf P\{X{\leqslant}t\} =1-e^{-\lambda t}$, means we also have the *probability density function* (pdf), which is: $f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$.   This has utility.

$$f_X(t) := \dfrac{\mathrm d~F_X(t)}{\mathrm d~t\hspace{5ex}}$$

Comment: Good point on P(x=t) = 0... I'm on the discrete chapter and the continuous one is next! Question... what is the probability we won't have an earthquake until right after week 4? We can answer the probability of no earthquakes in the first 4 weeks... but what about the probability it happens at the start of week 5? Seems like P{X <= t} will not help...

Comment: Are you looking for the probability that the first earthquake will happen during the fifth week?  $\mathsf P\{4{<}X{\leqslant} 5\}= e^{-4\lambda}-e^{-5\lambda}$

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.